# Pusher events are not received in Nuxtjs pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-echo, pusher-js, nuxtjs

I use `laravel-echo` for working with `pusherjs` in Nuxtjs.

**nuxt.config.js** section for pusherjs configuration:

```
buildModules: [
    [
      '@nuxtjs/laravel-echo', {
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: 'my-key-here',
        cluster: 'eu',
        forceTLS: true
      }
    ]
  ],
```

**package.json**

```
"vue": "^2.6.12",
"nuxt": "^2.14.3",
"pusher-js": "^7.0.0",
"@nuxtjs/laravel-echo": "^1.1.0",
```

**pages/test.vue**

```
<script>    
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$echo.channel('ch').listen("ev", (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

I manually send Event via Pusherjs's `Debug Console` but nothing happens in chrome's console.

[image: pusherjs debug console]

I'm sure the key and my app is connected to pusherjs correctly; because when I refresh the page, the logs appear in pusherjs's debug console:

[image]

So why are the events not received in front end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was because of `v1.1.0` of `@nuxtjs/laravel-echo`.

I used:

```
this.$echo.channel("ch").on("ev", (res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

instead of:

```
this.$echo.channel('ch').listen("ev", (res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

And the problem solved! (just replace `on` with `listen`)

Reference:

https://github.com/nuxt-community/laravel-echo/issues/17#issuecomment-637520496

Answer (score 1):

I have followings:

```
"nuxt": "^2.14.3",
"pusher-js": "^7.0.0",
"@nuxtjs/laravel-echo": "^1.1.0",
```

And I've to use:

```
this.$echo.channel("channel").on("event", (res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Although its [document](https://github.com/nuxt-community/laravel-echo) says to use:

```
this.$echo.channel("channel").listen("event", (res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Means I've to chain "on" method instead of "listen". Hope, this will be helpful!